# Family Sharing iPhone - Unique Question about purchases

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, sharing, mobile-device-management

I want to know if someone in my family share group still has an app downloaded on their phone. Is there a way to tell if they have deleted the app from their device?  I know all about hiding apps and how they cannot be deleted and all that. I get all that.

For example, I know about an app I told my kid he cannot use.  Well, its always going to show up on his downloaded list - but is there a way to see if he has put it back on his phone or not via family sharing.   (kid has adult privileges in family sharing, he is a teenager and I don't use any of the other parental controls nor do I want to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Sign up for a free MDM solution and enroll your child's iOS device under management.

- add the app(s) in question to management

You then get telemetry and reporting if that app is installed.

I prefer JAMF now, but there are several options. I’d start with this and then research others once this one has some specific drawbacks for you.

- https://support.jamfnow.com/

You won’t need DEP or VPP to run family devices under management.

Comment: I appreciate your response. That seems like a good tool. Does this mean that you don't know of a way within native iOS to tell if the app is currently on their phone or not via family share?

Comment: @JBG I suppose you could line up the progeny and inspect their settings manually. Or you could slow things down and connect them one by one to iTunes and page through app after app. The big flaw in those options is you can't really inspect an installation right after one inspection and removal right before the next inspection. MDM is the official way to control app installation at the moment the install happens. Plus you get all sorts of extra features.